# How to get a token from google without a redirect?

Tags: php, android

I have made a PHP script, and I will call it in java using a HTML get method. My java application needs to read the response from the script.

In the script, I need to get an access token from google. The only way to get an access token from google is the exchange a code google gives you with your client ID. So, I decided to do this to get the code in the script:

```
if(!isset($_GET["code"])){ //We need to get the code from google to exchange for an access key
    header("Location: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher&response_type=code&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=xxx&client_id=xxx");
    return;
}
```

This works great when I enter the script in my browser as a URL. If the code is not given as a parameter (which it never will) it will redirect to google and google will do a call back with a code paramater. However, due to this, the script does not work on my application. I cannot read any response from my script because of this redirect. What is a good workaround I can use to still get a fresh code from google but not have to use a redirect which inadvertently causes my app to not be able to get a response?

Comment: Why not use the Google Android sdk and then call the URL once form the cleint?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Call "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher&response_type=code&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=xxx&client_id=xxx" from the app?

Comment: Also, the link would expose my client ID, which would not be good to compile into the app